# Finding mail in Outlook Inbox not responded/replied to

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook 2013 or higher, is there a way to find/filter mail in an Inbox that I have received and read, but have not yet responded/replied to?

Ideally, I'm looking for an advanced search query so that I'd be able to quickly locate mail that I may have forgotten to respond to.

Comment: Is this email also marked as Unread?

Comment: Very interesting question. It might be worth finding which exact fields of e-mail messages which can be queried to retrieve the status. If I'll find some time, I'll perhaps try to make research to find exact answer better than currently offered signature workaround.

Comment: Perhaps, you can have a look at this question http://superuser.com/questions/324923/where-is-you-replied-to-this-message-on-data-stored-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add a unique text to your signature. Every time you reply to an e-mail, your signature will be included with the reply. If your signature has the keyword `LeonardNelson2016` then performing a Custom Search with a keyword exclusion (along with other criterias) in search will bring up all the relevant e-mails without this keyword and e-mails without a reply.

Here's what I have as a Search Folders:

[image]

I made my signature white with a font of 1. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Though this is good, I am looking for the ability to use a search keyword so that this could work in the absence of a unique string.

Comment: No, there isn't a way. While you may be able to discern what e-mail you have not replied to, it is not easy for Outlook to do it automatically. Maybe it'd be easier to reply to e-mails or figure out a different/better way to do your job. Slack replacing e-mail for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

an another way is to read about [email headers](https://www.gmass.co/blog/email-header/) fields of messages and then to apply knowledges. Responded emails contains in the header fields referring to original message, for example, *'In-Reply-To'*. The example of the procedure of processing is described on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/filtering-messages-i-have-not-responded-to/a343d27d-4d7b-4e7b-9868-9ca29ef1d48c) or [extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3547-outlook-find-filter-unanswered-messages.html). This solution is complicated but quite flexible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).